# How to retrieve CPU and memory metrics for all Azure App Services

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-web-app-service, metrics

I am trying to retrieve CPU and memory metrics (Max, Min, Avg) for all App Services in a specific Azure subscription:

```
 # Connect to Azure account
 Connect-AzAccount -UseDeviceAuthentication

 # Specify the subscription ID
 $subscriptionId = "<subscription-id> "

 # Get all App Services in the subscription
 $appServices = Get-AzWebApp

# Specify the time range for metrics retrieval
$startTime = (Get-Date).AddDays(-90) 
 $endTime = Get-Date                 
# Iterate through each App Service and retrieve metrics
foreach ($appService in $appServices) {
$appServiceName = $appService.Name
$resourceGroup = $appService.ResourceGroup

Write-Host "Retrieving metrics for App Service: $appServiceName"

# Retrieve CPU metrics
$cpuMetrics = Get-AzMetric -ResourceId $appService.Id `
                          -StartTime $startTime `
                          -EndTime $endTime `
                          -MetricNames "CpuPercentage" `
                          -Aggregation "Maximum", "Minimum", "Average"

# Retrieve memory metrics
$memoryMetrics = Get-AzMetric -ResourceId $appService.Id `
                             -StartTime $startTime `
                             -EndTime $endTime `
                             -MetricNames "MemoryPercentage" `
                             -Aggregation "Maximum", "Minimum", "Average"

# Display the metrics
Write-Host "CPU Metrics:"
$cpuMetrics | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Data | Select-Object -Property             
Timestamp, Maximum, Minimum, Average

Write-Host "Memory Metrics:"
$memoryMetrics | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Data | Select-Object -Property 
Timestamp, Maximum, Minimum, Average
}
```

But this code gives this error:

Get-AzMetric:
Line |
|  …                          -Aggregation "Maximum", "Minimum", "Average"
|                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type
'System.Nullable`1[Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Models.AggregationType]'
required by parameter 'AggregationType'. Specified method is not supported.

I am expecting the azure app service metrics to get listed

Answer (score 0):

Thank you I found it:

```
# Install the Azure Monitor module

Install-Module -Name Az.Monitor -Force

# Authenticate to your Azure account

Connect-AzAccount -UseDeviceAuthentication

# Specify the subscription ID and resource group name

$ResourceGroupName = "-------------”

$subscriptionId = "-------------”

# Specify the metric details

$cpuMetricName = "CpuTime"

$memoryMetricName = "MemoryWorkingSet"

$startTime = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)

$timeGrain = [System.TimeSpan]::FromMinutes(5)

# Get a list of all Azure App Services in the specified resource group

$appServices = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName

# Create an empty array to store the results

$results = @()

# Iterate through each App Service and retrieve the CPU and Memory metrics

foreach ($appService in $appServices) {

$appServiceName = $appService.Name

$resourceId = $appService.Id



# Get the CPU metrics

$cpuMetrics = Get-AzMetric -ResourceId $resourceId -MetricName $cpuMetricName -         
StartTime $startTime -TimeGrain $timeGrain -Aggregation " Total"

$averageCpuUsage = ($cpuMetrics.Data | Measure-Object -Property Total -Sum).Sum / 3600

# Get the Memory metrics

$memoryMetrics = Get-AzMetric -ResourceId $resourceId -MetricName         
$memoryMetricName -StartTime $startTime -TimeGrain $timeGrain -Aggregation "Average"

$averageMemoryUsage = ($memoryMetrics.Data | Measure-Object -Property Average -Average).Average/1Mb



# Create a custom object with the results

$result = [PSCustomObject]@{

    "App Service" = $appServiceName

    "Average CPU Usage (%)" = $averageCpuUsage

    "Average Memory Usage (MB)" = $averageMemoryUsage

}



# Add the result to the array

$results += $result

}

# Display the results in a table format

$results | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

The thing now is how to convert CPU Time to % of usage?